# Access an IP camera with Raspberry Pi2, OpenCV and GStreamer: Gstremaer unable to start pipeline

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, ip-camera, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to get frames from an IP camera. I can get frames with FFMPEG or GStreamer from my Ubuntu 14.04 PC and `omxplayer` or `gst-launch-1.0` from Raspberry Pi. But when I want to access camera with c++ OpenCV from Raspberry Pi, it is giving me an error about GStreamer pipeline;

```
(ocvip:2870): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtsp.so': /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrtsp.so: undefined symbol: gst_rtsp_connection_set_tls_validation_flags
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module u-uridecodebin, reported: URI was not accepted by any element
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline) in icvStartPipeline, file /opt/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 383
what(): /opt/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:383: error: (-2) GStreamer unable to start pipeline in function icvStartPipeline

Aborted
```

code:

```
const string videoAddress = "rtsp://user:password@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxx/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1";
int main() {
  cv::VideoCapture video;
  cv::Mat im;
  cv::namedWindow("IP", 1);
  video.open(videoAddress);
  if (video.isOpened()) {
    video >> im;
    if (!im.data) break;
    cv::imshow("IP", im);
    if (cv::waitKey(20) >= 0) break;
  }
}
```

I can access camera with same rtsp address, omxplayer is showing normal gst-launch is showing frames rotated by 180 degrees. I've built GStreamer-1.0 using [this page](http://www.onepitwopi.com/raspberry-pi/gstreamer-1-2-on-the-raspberry-pi/) because prebuilt libraries hasn't found by cmake. I found [this issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3953). There are two fixes int this bug but I'm not sure are these the correct solutions and solve my problem because I'm not accessing camera with `video.open(0)` so I couldn't do like `video.open(IPAddress + CV_CAP_PVAPI)`?

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to change the files but still same, I've built opencv-master still same.

Comment: I've compiled gstreamer-1.4.5 and it's working correctly with opencv from raspberry pi but when compiled and installed gstreamer/ we must define the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH then starts to compile for gst-ocr (if wanted) -> gst-plugins-base (when installed, we need to define GST_PLUGIN_PATH) -> gst-plugins-good -> gst-plugins-ugly -> gst-plugins-bad -> gst-omx (when installed, define GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR=${install-dir}/etc/xdg). Now playing rtsp without rotation and working with opencv but still slow so I don't know will opencv give gstreamer with omx support or also is giving?